# How Jquery scope gets passed to ready() methods callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got the following code from `JQuery.noConflict()` docs

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

As we can see, the `ready` methods callback function accepts a parameter but where are we passing this parameter ?

Comment: The thing that calls the callback (i.e. jQuery) passes in the value for this parameter, which is fine, because jQuery knows about itself *independently* of the `window.$` variable. jQuery uses a variation of the "module pattern".

Comment: what do you want to do???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"We"` aren't passing it into the function. The `jQuery` library is passing it, the `jQuery` API itself (which is the jQuery object), into the function callback.

See Also: [**Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)